# Google Video embedded in the Youtube IFrame

Tags: youtube-iframe-api

I am curious if it is possible to use this api with embedded videos that are only on Google Drive? I am trying the code below and the player is loading, but I am unable to get it to control the the iframe. Is it just not possible?

```
<div class="view" id="viewer">
  <iframe id="player" 
          type="text/html" 
          width="640" height="390" 
          src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/<?= vidId ?>/preview?enablejsapi=1" 
          frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>

<script src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<script>
  var player;

  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady
      }
    });
  }

  function onPlayerReady(e) {
    console.log('player ready');
  }
</script>
```

If it is not possible with the youtube iframe api, is there anyway with javascript to start and stop videos?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was a way to control the iframe player google drive but it's don't work since august 2016. [Google drive embed NO iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779197/google-drive-embed-no-iframe)

Video just play without api control.